# windows showing no audio output device is installed

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

After a usual restart with my windows 10 PC (Lenovo P50) I am facing an issue with my audio
[image]

When I checked the sound settings it shows "No output device found"

[image]

My device manager also not showing anything related to sound

[image]

I tried manually installing the driver from device manager->Actions->Add Legacy Hardware. But that too didn't worked.

Below is my OS specifications
[image]

Any one facing this issue?

Comment: Try to install the [Audio driver](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p50/downloads/driver-list/component?name=Audio).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of our Dell Latitude users reported this exact problem after a May Windows 10 update. This is what worked to fix it.

(Found the answer several places on the internet, including here:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/audio-device-is-disabled-not-fixed/e98ad21b-bf91-4adb-85c5-b953d01d426e?messageId=0435da20-b6b5-4ce4-9e3f-da0f6a57b849&page=1)

1. Open an elevated command prompt.
2. type:  net localgroup Administrators /add networkservice
3. ENTER
4. type: net localgroup Administrators /add localservice
5. ENTER
6. type: exit
7. ENTER
8. Restart the computer.

Comment: This finally solved my problems that I was facing for months now, I tried reinstalling different drivers over and over, but nothing helped, until I found out that the drivers were not the problem. For users of other nalguage versions of Windows 10 than english, please note that the user group "Administrators" is localized, on my (German) Windows I had to replace it with Administratoren (which is the German plural of administrator). But then, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Reboot.  Then go to: Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound

Under Devices and Printers, click "Add a device".  This should scan your system for any unmanaged hardware.  If your audio device is present, it will find it and add the driver.  If it doesn't find it, then it is likely a hardware problem.

Comment: Tried but its showing no devices found

Comment: P50 built-in audio is a common Realtek device, so it is either broken or disabled somehow.  Maybe check in BIOS settings?

Comment: Interesting thing is I can connect a Bluetooth Headset and its showing up.